# Spring JPA - Updating one table is updating another table in the backend

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JPA in my project and trying to update one table but it is trying to update another tbale before updating my actual table. Here is my code:
My service class:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl {
@Autowired
    private Table1Repository table1Repo;
@Autowired
    private Table2Repo table2Repo;
private void updateDataBaseAction(){
table1Repo.save(Table1);
}
}

@Repository
public interface Table1Repository extends CrudRepository<Table1, table1Id> {
}
@Repository
public interface Table2Repo extends CrudRepository<Table2, table2Id> {
}
```

Entity classes are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE2")
@Component
public class TABLE1Base {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CROS_REF_ID")
    private Long CrosRefNbr;
        
    @Column(name = "STRT_DT")
    private Date strtDt;
    
    @Column(name = "CPTR_DT")
    private Date CptrDt;
    
    @Column(name = "BAS_ST_CD")
    private String basStCD;
    
    @Column(name = "END_DT")
    private Date endDt;
    
    @Column(name = "ADD_EVNT_ID")
    private Long addEvntId;
    
    @Column(name = "LST_UPDT_EVNT_ID")
    private Long lstUpdtEvntId;

    @Column(name = "VOID_EVNT_ID")
    private Long voidEvntId;
    --few more columns as above
    
--setter and getter
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE1")
@Component
public class Table1 {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private Table1Id table1Id;

    @Column(name = "CROS_REF_ID")
    private Long crosRefId;

    
    @Column(name = "TYP_CD")
    private String TypCd;
    
    --few more columns with @column annotation
    
    --setter and getters
}
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Exception logs which i got when i inspect is:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
```

Error log which i am able to see on console is:

```
Hibernate: update TABLE2 set CPTR_DT=?, ADD_EVNT_ID=?, BAS_ST_CD=?, END_DT=?, LST_UPDT_EVNT_ID=?, SYS_CD=?, SRC_NBR=?, STRT_DT=?, VOID_EVNT_ID=? where CROS_REF_ID=?
[basics-inbound-customerstructure] [14-05-2021 09:07:47.912 ] [ERROR][http-nio-8085-exec-2] [ne.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper][ndc[]] - ORA-20001: THE NEW START DATE |01-JAN-20 NEW CAPTURE DATE |21-APR-21 NEW CROSS REF ID |167341354| NEW ADD EVENT ID |78639570006|.
ORA-06512: at "TRG_TAB2_NO_UPD", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TRG_TAB2_NO_UPD'
2021-05-14 09:07:50.290 ERROR 30164 --- [nio-8085-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/customerstructure] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.optum.basics.exception.DAOException: Error updating Object Type: 1] with root cause

com.optum.basics.exception.DAOException: Error updating Object Type: 1
    at com.optum.basics.customerstructure.service.impl.MyServiceImpl.updateDataBaseAction(MyServiceImpl.java)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.optum.basics.customerstructure.utils.LoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(LoggingFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The trigger it is showing is on table2 but actually i am trying to update my table1 and table1 is not having triggers to update table2.

Can you please share your thought on what i am missing and let me know for more information?

Comment: You autowire with a type Table2Repo but you show a repo Table2Repository - is there a repository Table2Repo also declared?

Comment: we are not able to imagine about your Entity, stacktrace is not matching the Code you attached. Which part of code is throwing  `com.optum.basics.exception.DAOException` ? can you add more code?

Comment: My apologies on typo error. It is table2Repo only.

Comment: I added error message from inspection of Exception

Answer (score 0):

It isn't immediately apparent what the issue is.

There is repo:

```
public interface Table2Repo extends CrudRepository<Table2, table2Id> {}
```

Whereas the entity is named `TABLE1Base`

Perhaps that is just confusing matters. I would suggest the problem is likely a hiccup in hibernate's naming strategy. Try sticking to the normal guidelines for naming:

1. Use Camel case for your entity names e.g. `Table1Base`
2. Use lower case names for your table names **or**, if the schema already exists, and you cannot change it, escape the table name i.e.

   `@Table(name = "\"TABLE1\"")`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by adding @DynamicUpdate annotation to my entity class.